# Swift 3: UISearchBar in Popover ViewController shows up wider than expected (on iPad)

Tags: swift, uitableview, ipad, swift3, uisearchbar

I have a view controller opened from a Popover segue - on iPhone displays this opens as a full page view controller (basically modally). On iPad it opens as a popover.

When opening the view on iPad the seachbar renders wider than the view of the popover. This does not occur on any of the iPhone screen sizes - Only iPad (as a Popover).

[image: iPad Popover View]

If I bring the UISearchBar to focus (tap on the textfield) the issue resolves itself until the view is opened again:

[image: iPad SearchBar in Focus]

[image: iPad SearchBar after Focus]

The UISearchBar is added programatically to a UIView of the desired dimensions.

[image: SearchBarView]

Here is the code for initializing the SearchController

```
        self.resultSearchController = ({
        let controller = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
        controller.searchResultsUpdater = self
        controller.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
        controller.searchBar.sizeToFit()
        controller.definesPresentationContext = false;

        searchBarView.addSubview(controller.searchBar)
        return controller
    })()
```

I have tried removing .sizeToFit() and instead sizing based on a CGSize

```
controller.searchBar.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: 375, height: 44)
```

This did not work however. I have also tried calling view.setNeedsLayout() and view.LayoutIfNeeded(). Neither of these have any effect.

I could solve this problem by making the UISearchBar active in viewDidLoad but am looking for a less janky solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this was an interesting lesson in debugging UI issues.

I believe this was ultimately caused by the ViewController being set to size inferred and size fixed. On different iPad screen sizes (9.7" vs 12.9").

To resolve this I set the frame width of the search bar to the tableview below it. I'm not sure why the searchbarview size changed width since its constrained to leading and trailing edges (superview).

```
        if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: Int(tableView.frame.width), height: 44)
    }
```

Although this works it has the same issue if split view is used (for widths where a popover has room to display).

Further suggestions are welcome but this is a good start.

*---Edit---*

Unchecking "Resize View from NIB" under layout in the ViewController as well as setting size to Freeform and declaring a constant width resolved the issue of the VC resizing on iPad. From there I just set the frame of the search bar in viewDidLoad as follows:

```
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        self.resultSearchController.searchBar.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 375, height: 44)
    }
```

Seems to work for all devices regardless of split view or not. There probably is a better way to do this without detecting iPads. Im thinking I'm missing a setting in Interface Builder.